# finding information inside of nested arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an array that stores the values:

```
var array = [['favorite color'],['black','red']]
```

to get `black` I would:

```
document.write(array[0][1][0]);
```

then if i append to the array another question `[['favorite thing']['box','ball']]`

If I wanted ball I would:

```
document.write.array[1][1][1];
```

I am having trouble understanding arrays. I want an array with one question and multiple answers then I want to loop through them and display everything. I can do the loop but I am unsure how to find things in nested arrays once I create them.

Comment: *"to get black I would: ... `array[0][1][0]`*. No, that would result in an error. This would imply a structure such as `[[...,['black',...]], ...]`. You would get black with `array[1][0]` because `array` has to two elements, both arrays, and you want to get the first element (`0`) of the second array (`1`).

Comment: You can always experiment on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of objects (which work like dictionaries) and arrays.  For example:

```
var array = [ 
  {'question' : 'favorite color', 'choices' : ['black','red'] },
  {'question' : 'favorite thing', 'choices' : ['box','ball'] }
]

for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    var question = array[i]['question'];
    var choices = array[i]['choices'];

    // here you can display / write out the questions and choices
}
```

Bearing in mind, creating a class and using a constructor or init methods would probably be better to encapsulate the idea of questions and answers.  But the above is the basic idea.

Comment: This is what i am trying to understand. this helps alot but how would i do this with numbers insead of words. How would i find ball? array[1][1][1]?

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [['favorite color'],['black','red','blue']];
document.writeln(array[1][1]);
document.write(array[1][2]);
```

​
Would print `red` then `blue` see it working live : http://jsfiddle.net/HJ872/

How?

```
array[0] => gets an *array* = ['favorite color'] 
           => array[0][0] gets this first element `favorite color`

array[1] => also gets this array = ['black','red','blue'] 
            => and then [1][1] will get 'red', [1][2] will get `blue`
```